# How to add Role assignments in Service Bus for Data Factory with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, servicebus

In Service Bus I'm trying to add permission for Data Factory. So at the end it should looks like that:

[image: Expected result]

I've already created resources with terraform, but Role Assigments is not working for some reason.

```
# Create Data Factory
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "adf" {
  name                = var.adf_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

# Create Service Bus
resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "sb_namespace" {
  name                = var.sb_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

# Create queue
resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "sb_queue" {
  name                  = var.sb_message_queue_name
  namespace_id          = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb_namespace.id
  max_size_in_megabytes = 1024
}

# Assign Data Factory to the Service Bus
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "roleassignment_sb" {
  scope                = azurerm_data_factory.adf.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Service Bus Data Sender"
  principal_id         = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb_namespace.identity[0].principal_id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_data_factory.adf
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any error? Also, which version of `azurerm` provider are you using?

Comment: No errors at all. `azurerm = { version = ">= 2, < 3" }`

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had to swap scope with principal source... So the correct code is:

```
# Assign Data Factory to the Service Bus
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "roleassignment_sb" {
  scope                = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb_namespace.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Service Bus Data Sender"
  principal_id         = azurerm_data_factory.adf.identity[0].principal_id
}
```